# JavaScript: How to find the highest random value score from two arrays

Tags: javascript

I am creating a game that has two arrays of scores. The array with the highest random score is the winner.

A for loop is being used to loop through both arrays to find the highest random score. A message will display saying if `score1` or `score2` is the winner.

I keep getting an error message that say:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: highScore is not defined"

How can I find the highest random score in a nested for loop and display the winner?.

Thank you for your time. Below is the code:

```js
function highestScore() {
  var score1 = [260, 57, 83, 53, 11, 33,
    56, 77, 64, 98, 45, 94,
    33, 45, 29, 40, 28, 57
  ];

  var score2 = [160, 157, 183, 153, 198, 111, 133];

  var highScore = 0; // hold highest score
  var winner;

  var randScore1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * score1.length);
  var randScore2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * score2.length);


  var get_randScore1 = score1[randScore1];
  var get_randScore2 = score2[randScore2];
  score1 = get_randScore1
  score2 = get_randScore2

  for (var i = 0; i < score1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < score2.length; j++) {
      if (score[i] > highScore) {
        highScore = score[i];
        winner = "Score1";
      } else if (score2[i] > highScore) {
        highScore = score2[i];
        winner = "Score2";
      }
    }
  }
  return highScore;
}

highestScore(console.log("Highest score: " + highScore + "." + " " + winner + " is the winner"));
```

Comment: Lemme get this straight:  Pick an element at random from score1.  Pick an element at random from score2.  The higher one wins.   Is there more to it than that?  Are you intending to repeat this contest a number of times?

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to choose a random score from each array and compare them, or if you have two arrays of random scores and want to select the highest score from each array and compare them. It sounds more likely to be the latter, but others seem to have interpreted it the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key issue here is the need to restructure your code to achieve what you require. One approach would be to externalise the variables `var highScore;` and `var winner;` from `function highestScore() { .. }` so that the data can be accessed and logged after the function has been called.

Additionally, you shouldn't need to iterate the scores using any kind of loop to achieve what you require. You can instead just select random values from each of the arrays and compare those to determine a winner.

Also as a note, there are a few minor errors in your original code such as `score1 = get_randScore1`, and use of the undefined array `score`, however with the revisions made in the snippet below, these can be omitted from the solution:

```js
/* Move these varialbes outside of highestScore() */
var highScore = 0;
var winner;

function highestScore() {
  var score1 = [260, 57, 83, 53, 11, 33,
    56, 77, 64, 98, 45, 94,
    33, 45, 29, 40, 28, 57
  ];

  var score2 = [160, 157, 183, 153, 198, 111, 133];

  var randScore1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * score1.length);
  var randScore2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * score2.length);

  var get_randScore1 = score1[randScore1];
  var get_randScore2 = score2[randScore2];
  /*
  Remove this:
  score1 = get_randScore1
  score2 = get_randScore2
  */

  /* This achieves what the description in your question requires */
  if (get_randScore1 > get_randScore2) {

    highScore = get_randScore1;
    winner = "Score1";
  } else if (get_randScore2 > get_randScore1) {

    highScore = get_randScore2;
    winner = "Score2";
  } else {

    winner = "No winning score";
  }

  /*
  This doesn't seem to achieve what the description of your 
  question requires
    for (var i = 0; i < score1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < score2.length; j++) {
        if (score1[i] > highScore) {
          highScore = score1[i];
          winner = "Score1";
        } else if (score2[j] > highScore) {
          highScore = score2[j];
          winner = "Score2";
        }
      }
    }
    */

  /* Not needed:
  return highScore;
  */
}

/* Call function */
highestScore();

/* Log results */
console.log("Highest score: " + highScore + "." + " " + winner + " is the winner");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I doubt this is doing what is intended.  `j` isn't used in the loop.

Comment: @Wyck true - just updated the snippet to functionality align with what I think the author is trying to compute. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I would have put the console.log inside the function rather than changing the scope of the variables.  But either way, you've made your point that the error comes from the scope of the variables not being accessible to the console.log that tried to display them.  So that's good.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
highestScore(console.log("Highest score: " + highScore + "." + " " + winner + " is the winner"))
```

can be written as

```
var result = console.log("Highest score: " + highScore + "." + " " + winner + " is the winner");
highestScore(result);
```

and `highScore` within the `console.log(...)` can't be found, because it is only defined within the function `highestScore`, resulting in your error message.

Write it like this

```
function highestScore() {
  var score1 = [260, 57, 83, 53, 11, 33,
    56, 77, 64, 98, 45, 94,
    33, 45, 29, 40, 28, 57
  ];

  var score2 = [160, 157, 183, 153, 198, 111, 133];

  var highScore = 0; // hold highest score
  var winner;

  var randScore1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * score1.length);
  var randScore2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * score2.length);


  var get_randScore1 = score1[randScore1];
  var get_randScore2 = score2[randScore2];
  score1 = get_randScore1
  score2 = get_randScore2

  for (var i = 0; i < score1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < score2.length; j++) {
      if (score[i] > highScore) {
        highScore = score[i];
        winner = "Score1";
      } else if (score2[i] > highScore) {
        highScore = score2[i];
        winner = "Score2";
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("Highest score: " + highScore + "." + " " + winner + " is the winner")
  return highScore;
}

highestScore();
```

Also, you passed the `console.log(...)` as parameter of the function, which is not right. In your function declaration you did define the function without any parameters.

Comment: Your console.log line comes after a 'return' at which point the function call exits so that line will never be reached!